# Can the array variable values persist when VBA macro finishes

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variable-declaration

Can the array variable values persist when macro finishes? I have declared a global variable:

```
Option Explicit
Public Arr2D As Variant

Public Sub ReadDataToArr()
    Arr2D = [MyNamedRange].Value
End Sub
```

but as soon as the macro finishes then `Arr2D` becomes out of context and `Arr2D` gets empty. I would like to read data to all array variables as Workbook opens and use them on whatever occasion I want without declaring and filling them every time.

**Update**. Why do I think it is empty? Add a Watch for `Arr2D` variable.

When I am in debug mode of macro above (hitting F8) I see this:
[image]

When I come with F8 hits to the macro end then I see this:
[image]

**Update again.** I noticed something strange to me. When I run the above macro second time in debug mode (after initializing values, and after the variable got out of context), then immediately in the very first line of the macro, the variable becomes "filled" with values, and in the context. So maybe that is why disagreement in comments arouse.

Comment: Can you show the code to proof this *"becomes out of context and Arr2D gets empty"*? I disagree. [mcve] might help.

Comment: @PEH I edited it.

Comment: Note that you watch in the context of `Module1.ReadDataToArr` so of course if you exit `ReadDataToArr` that context is invalid. But you just watch on the wrong context, the variable and its data persists. Proof: Add another sub and put `Debug.Print Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr2D), ",")` into it then run first `ReadDataToArr` then the other sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public test As Variant

Sub a()
    test = 5
End Sub

Sub b()
    MsgBox test
End Sub
```

First run `a` then run `b` it will output `5` as expected.

The variable `test` will persist until you run `End` or press the `stop` button in VBE.

---

Note that you should test in every procedure if your variable `test` was initialized.

for example

```
Option Explicit

Public Arr2D As Variant

Sub InitArr2D()
    Arr2D = [MyNamedRange].Value
End Sub

Sub ProcedureUsingArr2D()
    If Arr2D Is Nothing Then
        InitArr2D
    End If

    Debug.Print Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Arr2D), ",")
End Sub
```

If you don't test your variable might be `Nothing` after a runtime error occured and you pressed `End`. This way it gets automatically re-initialized.

Comment: When whatever macro, or trying to be precise, a sub finishes, does it release memory? I mean having initialized a huge array variable (having assigned values to it), is it kept in memory after sub finishes and is it somehow "reborn" or declared and broght to life when whatever new sub starts?

Comment: It keeps `Arr2D` in memory if it is a global variable which it is. So if it is a huge amount of data think about that Excel has a 2GB memory limit. • See my additional edit to ensure the array is initialized. • You just didn't see the array after the sub finished because you were looking in the wrong context. You were looking in the sub's context instead of a global context. If you look at the global context you will always see it.

Comment: How to release the memory if variable is not needed anymore? ReDim?

Comment: `Set Arr2D = Nothing`